# prevent fast multi request expressjs nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have project that count bottles using express.js, node.js and mongoose. (decrease and increase)

My server

```
app.post("/give",function(req,res){
Bottle.findById({type: "coca"}, function (err, data) {
    if(data.amount <= 0) return res.json({message: "Not enough coca"});
    data.amount -= 1;
    data.save();
    return res.json({message: "Give success"});
})
}
```

I edit my database **amount = 1**

Then I make fast http request to /give (loop 10)

So my server accept 5, not accept 5, and in my databse **amount = -5**
because it **return** `if(data.amount <= 0) return res.json({message: "Not enough coca"});`

I want nerver get bellow 0
What should I do? Thanks.

Sorry my bad English

**Edit**

I have to try add `console.log('hello word');`before `data.amount -= 1;` and it log **6 times**! Why???

**Edit**

The problem resolve at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49738185/9615416)

call to return res.json({message: "Give success"}); will complete BEFORE `data.save();` is complete.

```
app.post("/give",async(req,res)=>{
    const bottle = await Bottle.findById({type: "coca"}).exec;
    if(bottle.amount <= 0) return res.json({message: "Not enough coca"});
    bottle.amount -= 1;
    await bottle.save();
    res.json({message: "Give success"}); 
}
```

Comment: question is not clear, you edit the database value, the call /give 10 times and you see -5 in your database?

Comment: You want: -10 or to never get below 0?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788096/decrement-value-in-collection-until-0

Comment: I want never get below 0

Comment: You need a database operation that will atomically increase or decrease a value.  As you have it here, you have a race condition between the `findById()` and the `.save()` so your code is not multi-user safe.  Alternatively, you can create your own mutex so you won't start another counting operation until this one finishes.  I don't know your database specifically, but perhaps see this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: Yes,I think so too. But I don't know any solution. My code is unsafe. Could you help me post a guide comment