# Synchronization multi request payment express nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Today I am building RESTful API recharge money with mongoose. This include increase and decrease. I want amount never get bellow than 0.

No problem if multi request increase by one account. But I request very very fast multi request recharge a account It broken!!!!

This is a example decrease money of a account:

```
app.post("/recharge",function(req,res){
    Bottle.findById({user: "foo"}, function (err, user) {
    if(user.money <= 0) return res.json({message: "Not enough money"});
    else {
        user.money -=5000;
        user.save();
        return res.json({message: "Give success"});
        }    
    })
}
```

I set **foo** money = **5000**

Then a make fast 10 request in 0.001s. Then I check my database It show fo money **-25000**

It is not Synchronization?

why  `if(user.money <= 0) return res.json({message: "Not enough money"});` didn't work?

Help me please. Every answer will be accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to use brackets `{}` and also your call to `return res.json({message: "Give success"});` will complete BEFORE `user.save();` is complete.

`async-await` example given below with error handling omitted.

```
app.post("/recharge", async (req,res) => {
    const user = await Bottle.findById({user: "foo"}).exec();

    if (user.money <= 0) {
        res.json({message: "Not enough money"});
        return;
    }

    user.money -= 5000;
    await user.save()

    res.json({message: "Give success"});
}
```